# Validation of sub procedure before writing to file

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue with my data validation for my program. It correctly displays the MessageBox with the error as it is supposed to if the user inputs incorrect data. However when you close the MessageBox instead of clearing and setting focus on the offending TextBox, it continues to run the remaining sub procedures. Though the data written to the text file will halt at the data point that was incorrectly entered.

Now I know I am missing something that is most likely very simple, but I am taking classes to learn. Unfortunately the book is kind of vague and I cannot find anything on a Google search. Probably due to not asking the right question. So any guidance to what I am missing.

The purpose of this assignment is to learn to use Classes. My code is based off of the one example the book has on the subject and the parameters of the assignment. Any other comments or suggestions is also welcomed.

```
Public Class Motors
    'Variables for Class
    Public strMotorID As String
    Public strDescription As String
    Public dblRPM As Double
    Public dblVoltage As Double
    Public strStatus As String

    'Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        Debug.WriteLine("Motor object being created.")
        strMotorID = String.Empty
        strDescription = String.Empty
        dblRPM = 0.0
        dblVoltage = 0.0
        strStatus = String.Empty
    End Sub

    'Motor ID property procedure
    Public Property MotorId() As String
        Get
            Return strMotorID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strMotorID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Description property procedure
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return strDescription
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strDescription = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'RPM property procedure
    Public Property RPM() As Double
        Get
            Return dblRPM
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            dblRPM = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Voltage property procedure
    Public Property Voltage() As Double
        Get
            Return dblVoltage
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            dblVoltage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Status property procedure
    Public Property Status() As String
        Get
            Return strStatus
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strStatus = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close() 'Close the form
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        Dim frmNewMotor As New NewMotorForm 'Declare new form for input
        frmNewMotor.ShowDialog() 'Call new form.
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class NewMotorForm
    Private Sub GetData(ByVal objMotor As Motors)'Sub to get data from user.
        Try
            'Validate motor id is 5 characters long.
            If Len(txtMotorID.Text) > 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Check Motor ID input.")

            ElseIf Len(txtMotorID.Text) < 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Check Motor ID input.")

            Else
                objMotor.MotorId = txtMotorID.Text 'Correctly passes to Class.
                objMotor.Description = txtDescription.Text 'Correctly passes to Class.

                If Double.TryParse(txtRPM.Text, objMotor.RPM) And CDbl(txtRPM.Text) >= 10 And CDbl(txtRPM.Text) <= 10000 Then
                    objMotor.RPM = CDbl(txtRPM.Text) 'Validate input is within appropriate range. Correctly passes to Class.

                Else
                    'Error message for invalid input
                    MessageBox.Show("Check RPM input.")
                    txtRPM.Clear()
                    txtRPM.Focus()

                End If

                If Double.TryParse(txtVoltage.Text, objMotor.Voltage) And CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) >= 1 And CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) <= 500 Then
                    objMotor.Voltage = CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) 'Validate input is within appropriate range.

                Else
                    'Error message for invalid input.
                    MessageBox.Show("Check Voltage input.")
                    txtVoltage.Clear()
                    txtVoltage.Focus()

                End If
                'Get selection from combobox
                If cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "ON" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "ON"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "OFF" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "OFF"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "MNT" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "MNT"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "NA" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "NA"
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please check Status input.")
                End If   

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Check data input.")
            txtMotorID.Focus()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveRecord(ByVal objMotor As Motors)
        Dim writer As StreamWriter 'Variable for StreamWriter
        Try
            writer = File.AppendText("Motors.txt") 'Open file to be written
            'Write data from variables to text document.
            writer.WriteLine(objMotor.strMotorID)
            writer.WriteLine(objMotor.strDescription)
            writer.WriteLine(objMotor.dblRPM)
            writer.WriteLine(objMotor.dblVoltage)
            writer.WriteLine(objMotor.strStatus)

            writer.Close() 'close document
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to save motor record.")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearForm()
        'Sub routine to clear the form after user saves file.
        txtMotorID.Clear()
        txtDescription.Clear()
        txtRPM.Clear()
        txtVoltage.Clear()
        cmbStatus.ResetText() 
        txtMotorID.Focus()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close() 'Close Form
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim objMotor As New Motors
        GetData(objMotor) 'Get data from Class
        SaveRecord(objMotor) 'Write data to document
        MessageBox.Show("Motor record saved.") 'Message to for completion.
        ClearForm() 'Clear form
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewMotorForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Debug.Listeners.Add(New ConsoleTraceListener())
    End Sub
End Class
```

I enter a boolean var to return a true or false into the GetData sub.

```
If Len(txtMotorID.Text) > 5 And Len(txtMotorID.Text) < 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Check Motor ID input.")
            dataInput = False

            Else
                objMotor.MotorId = txtMotorID.Text 'Correctly passes to Class.
                objMotor.Description = txtDescription.Text 'Correctly passes to Class.

                If Double.TryParse(txtRPM.Text, objMotor.RPM) And CDbl(txtRPM.Text) >= 10 And CDbl(txtRPM.Text) <= 10000 Then
                    objMotor.RPM = CDbl(txtRPM.Text) 'Validate input is within appropriate range. Correctly passes to Class.
            Else

                'Error message for invalid input
                MessageBox.Show("Check RPM input.")
                txtRPM.Clear()
                txtRPM.Focus()
                dataInput = False

                End If

                If Double.TryParse(txtVoltage.Text, objMotor.Voltage) And CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) >= 1 And CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) <= 500 Then
                    objMotor.Voltage = CDbl(txtVoltage.Text) 'Validate input is within approriate range. Does not pass data to Class.
                Else
                    'Error message for invalid input. 
                MessageBox.Show("Check Voltage input.")
                txtVoltage.Clear()
                txtVoltage.Focus()
                dataInput = False
                End If
                'Get selection from combobox
                If cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "ON" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "ON"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "OFF" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "OFF"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "MNT" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "MNT"
                ElseIf cmbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString = "NA" Then
                    objMotor.strStatus = "NA"
                Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please check Status input.")
                dataInput = False
                End If
            dataInput = True
        End If
```

Then used and If...Then statement on the btnSave_Click event:

```
If dataInput = True Then

        GetData(objMotor) 'Get data from user

        SaveRecord(objMotor) 'Write data to document

        MessageBox.Show("Motor record saved.") 'Message to for completion.
        ClearForm() 'Clear form
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Check input.")
    End If
```

However now, the program complete ignores all the MessageBoxes, TextBox.Clear, and TextBox.Focus that I have set in the event a user input invalid data.

Comment: `Exit Sub` where you want it to stop.  It might be better if it returned a boolean indicating if it validated or failed.  There is no need to use `CDbl` if your `Double.TryParse` succeeds - it will already have set the value

Comment: I like `Return` vs `Exit Sub`. At least `return` looks more like .net vs `Exit Sub` is probably VB6 compatibility :-). I am voting to close as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced ...this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.". WE know the answer

Comment: I believe I followed the advice of @Plutonix with the boolean. Edits are posted in the OP. It works to stop the procedures from running, but has created a new problem of ignoring the lines to indicate where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestions you can try.

Use function instead of `Sub`

```
Private Function GetData(ByVal objMotor As Motors) As Boolean
        If Len(txtMotorID.Text) <> 5 Then 'if MotorID length != 5 then take action for wrong input
            MessageBox.Show("Check Motor ID input.")
            txtMotorID.Clear() ' Clear the input
            txtMotorID.Focus() ' Focus to relevent textbox
            Return False 'return false
        End If
        'Use same logic to validate your other inputs
        'don't forget to return true if everything is fine
```

check the return value of the function to see whether it can be saved

```
If GetData(objMotor) Then 'If the data got is validated
    SaveRecord(objMotor) 'Write data to document
    MessageBox.Show("Motor record saved.") 'Message to for completion.
    ClearForm() 'Clear form
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now, that made a lot of the stuff I had been Googling much clearer.